# Accidentally removed a lot of drivers, etc. How can I reinstall them from a USB (no network access)?

Tags: drivers

Long story short, autoremove removed a ton of things including Settings, network-manager and many related network options, etc.

I still have ifconfig and can see my network cards, but I can't connect to anything. I've tried many command line methods of connections but nothing worked.

I cannot reformat this machine, and I cannot boot into the live USB and mount as it is an encrypted drive. I have to be able to pull the drivers off of another source, whether its from the live USB itself.

Is there any way to reinstall these drivers from the live USB packages or something? Any other suggestions on how I can fix this machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: I use clonezilla before doing major stuff to backup partitions (or drives)